# Access specific Laravel 5 route from a directory located elsewhere

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I have wordpress installed:

```
example.com
```

and laravel **/public** dir (which is accessed from api.example.com)

```
example.com/api
```

How do i access a laravel route say `/play`
from `example.com/play`

currently i have this `example.com/play/play` showing the correct laravel route, but i need it to go up a level.

**The setup** 
index.php in /home/public_html/play

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

this correctly points to the `/home/laravel` for example

then the routes file is

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'play'], function () {    
    Route::get('/', ['as'=>'/', 'uses'=>'Controller@play']);
});
```

i have added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(play/.*)$` to root .htaccess so wordpress doesn't take over.

and finally this is where i am hitting the problem:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /play/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

which is located in  `/home/public_html/play`

So how do i show the laravel route in the /play dir?
Can this be achieved with rewrite? 
Can i pass a parameter to laravel to tell it to start /play as the root?

Comment: Instead of mod_rewrite, try using: `Fallbackresource /play/index.php` in your httpd.conf. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I believe there is no change by using this approach, as it is still access the same file, in the same location. I need play/index.php to appear as ../index.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have multiple applications that you want to access it from single domain, the best implementation is to boot different server for each application. The you can set up proxy from the main application to other applications.

You can boot apache2 server for your laravel application with setup like this

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:8080>
  DocumentRoot "path-to-laravel-app"

  <Directory "path-to-laravel-app">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then set up proxy in your wordpress application `.htaccess` file like this

```
ProxyPass "/play"  "http://locahost:8080/play"
ProxyPassReverse "/play"  "http://locahost:8080/play"
```

Comment: This looks like what i was after, not sure my "shared" hosting allows be to do this, however i would like to give this a try. My main concern is when the server is reset will it reboot both application instances, or do i need to manually run each time (surely not)...

Comment: @HarryBosh if you set up the servers initially then you wont have to reboot your applications, only update the code. I would recommend you to use AWS instances instead of shared hosting. AWS is cheap for small applications and you have a lot more freedom in implementing your server. Also you can look up CI(Continuous Integration) services like `Circle CI`, `Travis Ci` or Bitbucket pipelines (last one is new and simple).